# Sql Query with GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, subquery

I have a table with 4 columns :- PaymentID,patient ID, paymentMode, totalPayment

I am trying to find the maximum total payment paid by a patient and the payment mode for it .

This is what i have tried :

```
SELECT paymentMode, MAX(totalPayment) AS MAXIMUM_PAYMENT FROM Payments
Group By paymentMode
```

This returns the maximum payment and payment mode , but the problem is, it gets grouped by payment mode ,so  when i execute this query i get 2 answers.

Below is a sample output which i get :

[image]

What i want is just one answer, simply meaning when considering to the above image, i want to output only the record in 2 row as it has more higher payment than the record in first row.  Is it possible to add a condition to the group By ?

How do i solve this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is a "maximum total payment"? A number is either a "maximum" or a "total", and both require a second dimension over which they are defined (i.e. a time period).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has four columns.  Do you want the mode for the maximum payment?  Or the mode that has the largest sum of payments?  The first would be this (for a single patient):

```
select p.*
from payments p
where patient = xxx
order by totalpayment desc
limit 1;
```

This returns the value for a single patient.

EDIT:

If you want the mode for the maximum payment for all patients, you can use this MySQL trick:

```
select patient, max(payment) as maxpayment,
       substring_index(group_concat(paymentmode), ',', 1) as maxpaymentmode
from payments p
group by patient
```

Comment: i want the mode for the maximum payment. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [HAVING](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAVING) after GROUP BY for more conditions

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total paid by a patient, why are you doing order by payment mode?

Try this:

```
SELECT paymentMode, MAX(totalPayment) AS MAXIMUM_PAYMENT FROM Payments
Group By patientID
```